# React удалить элемент li из списка ul

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент для реакта, который описывает элемент `<li>` списка. Логика работы компонента такая: он рендерит текст и `<span>` с крестиком внутри. На `<li>` и `<span>` вешаются обработчики кликов. При клике по li текст зачеркивается. При клике по span нужно удалить li из списка ul.

Я реализовал зачеркивание текста по клику. Как реализовать удаление li из ul? Как я понимаю, за удаление должен отвечать сам список, а не элемент li. В таком случае, как это сделать?

Почему нельзя инкапсулировать всю логику внутри li?

```
import React from "react";

class TodoItem extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: props.item, done: false };
    }

    render() {
        let style = this.state.done ? "done" : "";
        return (
            <li onClick={this.handleComplete} className={style}>
                {this.state.text}
                <span className="close" onClick={this.handleRemove}>{"\u00D7"}</span>
            </li>
        );
    }

    handleComplete = () => {
        this.setState({ done: !this.state.done });
    }

    handleRemove = () => {
        alert("remove");
    }
};

export default TodoItem;
```

Comment: Зачеркивание у вас тоже неверно реализовано. В теории у родителя должны быть методы которые будут заниматься удалением и изменением массива (только их и нужно передавать в `props`), а дочерний компонент должен их "дергать" передавая лишь нужные индексы. Это должен быть стейтлесс компонент.

Comment: То есть, если у меня есть компонент List, который генерит набор TodoItem, то именно List должен зачеркивать и удалять элементы?

Comment: const List = props => {
    return (
    <ul>
        {
            props.items.map((item, index) => <TodoItem item={item} />)
        }
    </ul>);
};

Comment: @MedvedevDev, компонент TodoList стейтфул, а TodoItem - стейтлесс, и TodoList в своем состоянии хранит массив заданий?

Comment: все верно, `TodoList` в своем `state` хранит массив объектов `state = { items: [ { text: 'Текст', done: false }, ... ] }` эти объекты и передаются в `TodoItem` вместе с методом который будет изменять `state`, при клике на что-то вызывается этот метод, меняет `state`, весь список перерисовывается в соответствии с новыми вводными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
const TodoItem = ({ text, done, handleComplete, handleRemove }) => (
  <li className={ done ? 'done' : '' }>
    <span onClick={ handleComplete }>{ text }</span>
    <span className="close" onClick={ handleRemove }>{"\u00D7"}</span>
  </li>
);

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { text: 'ListItem-1', done: false },
      { text: 'ListItem-2', done: false },
      { text: 'ListItem-3', done: false },
      { text: 'ListItem-4', done: false }
    ]
  };
  
  handleComplete = index => this.setState({
    items: this.state.items.map(( item, i ) => (
      i === index
        ? { ...item, done: true }
        : item)
    )
  });

  handleRemove = index => this.setState({
    items: this.state.items.filter(( item, i ) => i !== index)
  });

  render() {
    return this.state.items.map(( item, i ) => (
      <TodoItem
        key={ i }
        { ...item }
        handleComplete={ () => this.handleComplete(i) }
        handleRemove={ () => this.handleRemove(i) }
      />
    ));
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoList/>, document.getElementById('todo'));
```

```css
li.done { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="todo"></div>
```